# Two object types in a RecyclerView that each have their own ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Im trying to create recyclerview that displays the results of two different arrays from one single object (ObjectMaster). I dont care the order so much, just as long as both arrays are displayed in the list. Any ideas or suggestions would be extremely appreciated.

### Model

```
public ObjectMaster {
  List<Object1> first_objects;
  List<Object2> second_objects;
}
```

### Adapter

```
public class ObjectMasterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

 private ObjectMaster object;
 private static final int TYPE_OBJECT1 = 0;
 private static final int TYPE_OBJECT2 = 1;

 public ObjectMasterAdapter(ObjectMaster object) {
  this.object = object;
}

public class Object1Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  private TextView title;
  private TextView subtitle;

  public Object1Holder(View itemView) {
   super(itemView);
   title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
   subtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
  }
  public void bindObj(Object1 object) {
    title.setText(object.getTitle());
    subtitle.setText(object.getSubtitle());
  }
}
public class Object2Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  private TextView title;

  public Object2Holder(View itemView) {
   super(itemView);
   title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
  }
  public void bindObj(Object2 object) {
    title.setText(object.getTitle());
  }
}

 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {

  // I need to figure out the best way to determine if its already listed objects from the first object array (Object1)
 }

 @Override
 public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

  View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.object_item, viewGroup, false);
  switch(i) {
   case TYPE_OBJECT1: return new Object1Holder(view);
   case TYPE_OBJECT2: return new Object2Holder(view);
  }
  return null;
}

 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case TYPE_OBJECT1:
            Object1Holder object1 = (Object1Holder) viewHolder;
            object1.bindObj(object.first_objects.get(i));
            break;

        case TYPE_OBJECT2:
            Object2Holder object2 = (Object2Holder) viewHolder;
            object2.bindObj(object.second_objects.get(i));
            break;
    }
 }

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
     return object.first_objects.size() + object.second_objects.size();
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to figure out the best way to determine if its already listed objects from the first object array (Object1)

If `position` is bigger than (or equal to) the length of the first array, you are now into the second array. Subtract the length of the first array from the `position` to get the index into the second array.

Also note that you have a bug in `onBindViewHolder()`, in that you are not performing a similar subtraction to change the `position` (the `i` value) into the index into your second array, when it is the second array's view type that you're working on.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare , You were right, simple as subtracting the size of the first array when getting the start of the index on the 2nd array. It is working as expected now.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I am facing a related problem ... could you please help me out with my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34431734/3287204) ?